# What are the benefits of using Jasmine Framework on existing applications?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, frameworks

I got one project which contains JavaScript code. No unit tests were written for JavaScript code.

So it is feasible or beneficial to write unit test cases using Jasmine Framework for code?

What are benefits or challenges may I face while doing this?

Comment: As opposed to what? Not writing tests? Writing tests not using Jasmine? If you're asking about adding tests to existing code generally, there are whole *books* on this.

Answer (score 0):

The benefits over [other JavaScript testing frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/javascript-unit-test-tools-for-tdd) are really opinionated, you need to find the one you like yourself.

Here is what Jasmine has to say about itself:

> Jasmine is a behavior-driven development framework for testing your
>   JavaScript code. It does not depend on any other JavaScript
>   frameworks. It does not require a DOM.

I would research [**Jest**](https://facebook.github.io/jest/), it is based on Jasmine (build by Facebook). It includes everything you would need from a testing tool. Including mocking, code-coverage and more, but it sells it as Zero configuration, thus very easy to setup.